# $_SESSION isn't working when calling from another page

Tags: php, html, session

I am just trying to get session to work before implementing it into my code and can't seem to get it to. It's very basic and followed the code from w3 schools as well as looked up why it wouldn't work, but everything I find shows that it should work.

**Where I set $_SESSION (test1.php)**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["test"] = "test";
   echo $_SESSION["test"];
?>
```

**Where I call $_SESSION (test2.php)**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION["test"];
?>
```

**Error I Receive**

Undefined index: test in /home/hhw56gndsib6/public_html/test/test2.php on line 3

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to close out my browser to start a new session.